# SharedSizeGroup for Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

In Wpf we have SharedSizeGroup property to share the sizes, of lets say Columns, between Grids. Anybody aware about the similar functionality support in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Shared sizing is best implemented using element property bindings in Silverlight. Just make all your shared sized elements bind to the width/height of another.

**Refer Following:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SLTestApp.MainPage"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Extensions;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Extensions"
       mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" ext:SharedSize.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="firstfirstGrid" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  ext:SharedSize.SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ext:SharedSize.SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtFirstFirst" >
                    <Run>aa</Run>
                    <LineBreak />
                    <Run>aa</Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="firstsecondGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  ext:SharedSize.SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ext:SharedSize.SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBlock Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Link Referance:**

http://die-rooter.de/ITworks/archives/27-SharedSize-Grid-with-Silverlight.html

Hope Its Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<UserControl x:Class="SLTestApp.MainPage"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
       xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Extensions;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Extensions"
       mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" ext:SharedSize.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="firstfirstGrid" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  ext:SharedSize.SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ext:SharedSize.SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtFirstFirst" >
                    <Run>aa</Run>
                    <LineBreak />
                    <Run>aa</Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="firstsecondGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  ext:SharedSize.SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ext:SharedSize.SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBlock Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```